# Token Authorization with Axios is not working correctly

Tags: reactjs, axios, jwt

I'm practicing with admin Authorization using Axios and JWT and I'm having trouble with Axios' token authorization. My problems are that I can bypass the login page by doing localhost:3000/admin but when I do, I get an Axios Error: Request Failed 401. When I try using the admin login page and I log in correctly, I get the same error.

Here's my Admin Login setup:

```
const handleLogin = async (event) => {
event.preventDefault();

try {
  const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/admin/login', {
    username: username,
    password: password,
  });

  const token = response.data.token;

  localStorage.setItem('adminToken', token);
  console.log(token)

  navigate('/admin');
} catch (error) {

  console.error('Error during login:', error);
}
};
```

Here's my Admin setup:

```
function Admin() {
  const [listOfOrders, setListOfOrders] = useState([]);
  const navigate = useNavigate(); 

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('adminToken');

    if (token) {
      axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
    } else {
      navigate('/admin/login');
    }
  }, [navigate]);


  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:3001/getOrders").then((response) => {
      setListOfOrders(response.data);
    });
  }, []);
```

I've used console logs to verify that the tokens so are the same so I'm sure the jwt and bcrypt authentication used in the backend is working. But I'm a bit lost on why the token isn't securing the admin page from being accessed and why I can't make requests to it even after logging in. Any feedback/ideas are much appreciated, thanks.